# How much money is fiat money?

Tags: commodities, cryptocurrency, money-supply

How much or what amount/percentage of all the money in the world actually [fiat money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiat_money)?

I am not looking for an accurate estimate obviously, but a ball park estimate... even if that was possible.

Also by all the money, I mean all the money in currency issued by recognized countries in the world.

Not including all crypto-currency which is essentially 100% fiat.

Comment: All of it, basically. No major currency is backed by gold now, and even minor currencies are more often backed by another country’s currency than by previous metals.

Comment: @MikeScott That is very surprising and interesting, I have seen in a video that one of UK's banks have gold bars which supposedly back some of their pounds.

Comment: Almost ever country has *some* gold.  That doesn't mean that currencies are tied to a certain percentage of the gold in their vaults.

Comment: I think that for most of the developed world you will find that the vast majority of money is fiat money, if not all. Very few countries, if any, have their money backed by gold or other precious metals. For all countries which use fractional reserve banking this must be true, since there is really very little way to uphold the relationship between money supply and gold.

Comment: There's a real easy answer: All of it.

Comment: Thank you for all the input guys! Sad to see that this question has been put on hold. I at-least have some useful insight now... I thought at least some of the the currencies had some commodities backing them

Answer (score 1):

After 1971 (Nixon Shock), dollar was decoupled from gold. Hence, by definition, US Dollar is "fiat money".

Since a currency as powerful as dollar is technically "fiat money", I don't think you have to make guesses regarding other currencies. After 20th century, most are legal tenders backed by governments.

Cryptos are criticized by economists because they do not have the backing of governments.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I would like to see a more detailed one with more citations and references so I will wait a bit and do some research in the meanwhile.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Yes I agree, my point was that since all powerful dollar is fiat, most currencies would be fiat money as well.